# Adding objects to a GroupBox issue

Tags: c#, wpf, runtime

I am trying to add different objects to a GroupBox. When I click 'Add Title' button I can get the Combobox and Textbox to appear in the Groupbox.

**What I want to now happen is when they click 'Add question' I want to be able to add the questions objects (Combobox, Textbox) to the same Groupbox as the last added title.**

C# CODE:

```
private void btnAddTitle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        CurrentSortItem++;
        SortItems.Add(CurrentSortItem);

        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
        gp = new GroupBox();

        ComboBox y = new ComboBox();
        y.Name = "Combo" + CurrentSortItem;
        y.SelectedItem = CurrentSortItem;
        y.Height = 25;
        y.Width = 45;
        y.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        y.Margin = new Thickness(20, 15, 0, 0);

        foreach (int item in SortItems)
        {
            y.Items.Add(item);
        }

        TextBox x = new TextBox();
        x.Name = "Title" + CurrentSortItem;
        x.Text = "Title...";
        x.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
        x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        x.Height = 25;
        x.Width = 200;
        x.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        x.Margin = new Thickness(12, 15, 0, 0);

        sp.Children.Add(y);
        sp.Children.Add(x);

        gp.Content = sp;



        spStandard.Children.Add(gp);

}

private void ViewQuestions(StackPanel sp)
{
        gp.Content = sp;
}

    List<int> SortItems1 = new List<int>();
    int CurrentSortItem1 = 0;
    int Count = 0;

private void btnQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        if (SortItems.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must add a title before adding a question", "ERROR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            Count++;

            CurrentSortItem1++;
            SortItems1.Add(CurrentSortItem1);

            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };



                ComboBox y = new ComboBox();
                y.Name = "Combo" + CurrentSortItem1;
                y.SelectedItem = CurrentSortItem1;
                y.Height = 25;
                y.Width = 45;
                y.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                y.Margin = new Thickness(20, 15, 0, 0);

                foreach (int item in SortItems1)
                {
                    y.Items.Add(item);
                }

                TextBox x = new TextBox();
                x.Name = "Question" + CurrentSortItem1;
                x.Text = "Question...";
                x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
                x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                x.Height = 25;
                x.Width = 500;
                x.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                x.AcceptsReturn = true;
                x.Margin = new Thickness(100, 15, 0, 0);

                TextBox z = new TextBox();
                z.Name = "Points" + CurrentSortItem;
                z.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                z.Height = 25;
                z.Width = 45;
                z.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                z.Margin = new Thickness(250, 15, 0, 0);

                sp.Children.Add(y);
                sp.Children.Add(x);
                sp.Children.Add(z);

                ViewQuestions(sp);

    }
```

I have tried to have an attempted but when I click 'Add Question' it just overwrites the Title's objects.

Any help would be amazing.

**I am using WPF, and these are created at runtime.**

Thanks.

EDIT4:

I have had to move

```
StackPanel outerSp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
GroupBox gp;
```

Just below the

```
public partial class CreateNewStandard : Page
{
```

So it is visible to all the methods. Then I get this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9uqF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void btnAddTitle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    CurrentSortItem++;
    SortItems.Add(CurrentSortItem);

    StackPanel outerSp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
    gp = new GroupBox();

    ComboBox y = new ComboBox();
    y.Name = "Combo" + CurrentSortItem;
    y.SelectedItem = CurrentSortItem;
    y.Height = 25;
    y.Width = 45;
    y.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    y.Margin = new Thickness(20, 15, 0, 0);

    foreach (int item in SortItems)
    {
        y.Items.Add(item);
    }

    TextBox x = new TextBox();
    x.Name = "Title" + CurrentSortItem;
    x.Text = "Title...";
    x.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
    x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    x.Height = 25;
    x.Width = 200;
    x.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    x.Margin = new Thickness(12, 15, 0, 0);

    sp.Children.Add(y);
    sp.Children.Add(x);

    outerSp.Children.Add(sp);
    gp.Content = outerSp;

    spStandard.Children.Add(gp);

}

private void ViewQuestions(StackPanel sp)
{
var stackPanel=gp.Content as StackPanel;
if(stackPanel!=null)
{
    stackPanel.Children.Add(sp);
 }
else
   gp.Content=sp;
}

List<int> SortItems1 = new List<int>();
int CurrentSortItem1 = 0;
int Count = 0;

private void btnQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (SortItems.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must add a title before adding a question", "ERROR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        Count++;

        CurrentSortItem1++;
        SortItems1.Add(CurrentSortItem1);

            ComboBox y = new ComboBox();
            y.Name = "Combo" + CurrentSortItem1;
            y.SelectedItem = CurrentSortItem1;
            y.Height = 25;
            y.Width = 45;
            y.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            y.Margin = new Thickness(20, 15, 0, 0);

            foreach (int item in SortItems1)
            {
                y.Items.Add(item);
            }

            TextBox x = new TextBox();
            x.Name = "Question" + CurrentSortItem1;
            x.Text = "Question...";
            x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
            x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            x.Height = 25;
            x.Width = 500;
            x.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            x.AcceptsReturn = true;
            x.Margin = new Thickness(100, 15, 0, 0);

            TextBox z = new TextBox();
            z.Name = "Points" + CurrentSortItem;
            z.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            z.Height = 25;
            z.Width = 45;
            z.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            z.Margin = new Thickness(250, 15, 0, 0);

            sp.Children.Add(y);
            sp.Children.Add(x);
            sp.Children.Add(z);

            outerSp.Children.Add(sp);

            ViewQuestions(sp);

}
```

You are overwriting it .Though you need to add them to the already existing stackPanel. The code is not tested I am trying to give you an idea .I hope this will help.

Comment: Is this for overwriting? as I don't want it to overwrite I just want it to appear below like it does in a stack panel.

Comment: But it needs to be in the groupbox of the title?

Comment: aint gp the groupbox of title?

Comment: gp is a groupbox of title but then when they add a question it needs to be added to gp.

Comment: Have you copied and pasted the above code.The above code added it to Title groupBox and am expecting gp is class level field.

Comment: there is no extension method for .Children.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to write as StackPanel. I updated the answer.It should be var stackPanel=gp.Content as StackPanel;.Sorry for that.

Comment: This worked and it didnt overwrite the title, Can you check the edit2 out though as the question is appearing to the right of the title? I need to appear below? Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Once I will get on my laptop. I will post the solution.Yes thats a valid exception and we need to structure it in different way

Comment: yeah thats fine thanks alot for this, i am going to be away till Thursday now but i will make sure i will get back to you.

Comment: I updated the answer .Though its badly indented. But hope will work as u expected.